# add repo key using puppet under ubuntu

Tags: puppet

I'll need to add a apt repository key to a bunch of ubuntu hosts using puppet.

Would a statement like this work for that?

```
 exec {"add apt key for elastic":
        command => "/usr/bin/curl https://packages.elasticsearch.org/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | /usr/bin/apt-key add -",
     }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should work but this will also apply the same configuration whenever you rerun Puppet.

From [exec docs](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#exec):

> Any command in an exec resource must be able to run multiple times without causing harm — that is, it must be idempotent. There are three main ways for an exec to be idempotent:
>
> - The command itself is already idempotent. (For example, apt-get update.)
> - The exec has an onlyif, unless, or creates attribute, which prevents Puppet from running the command unless some condition is met.
> - The exec has refreshonly => true, which only allows Puppet to run the command when some other resource is changed. (See the notes on refreshing below.)

Comment: Great thanks! How would I get the exec command to run only once per host? Thanks

Comment: @bluethundr You should implement an expression that verify if the key was already added. If your expression return `0` or `true` if a key has been added you should use `unless`, otherwise you should use `onlyif`. See the samples in the [doc](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#exec).

Answer (score 0):

I try and only use execs if I really have to. One of the reasons being that you have to code the exec so that it only runs when you want to. Instead, you can use the [apt](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apt#add-gpg-keys) module. This will only place the key on the host if it does not already exist. The resource is under puppet control so will not be added on subsequent runs:

```
  include apt

  apt::key { 'elasticsearch':
    id      => '46095ACC8548582C1A2699A9D27D666CD88E42B4',
    options => 'https://packages.elasticsearch.org/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch',
  }
```

Comment: how did you get the id?

Comment: @anudeep From the elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/setup-repositories.html#setup-repositories)